# Call javascript function on every second ( nearly 1800 seconds ) setTimeout & setInterval having lagging issue

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show login popup before 1 minute of session timeout.Max session idle timeout value is 1800 seconds ( 30 mins. ) So I used one counter variable like **idlecount**. Using setInterval() I am incrementing that variable value. So now when variable value is 1740 ( i.e my idle session timeout value 1800 - 60 sec. ) then I will show login popup ( Having 2 buttons (1) Keep me sign in (2) Sign out ).
The issue is that setInterval() not properly maintaing the value of variable **idlecount**. Due to that login popup not working properly.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. There is barely any question here. In the title you mentioned some “lag”, but your actual question doesn’t contain any actual info besides what you _want_ (and only telling us that is not enough.)

Comment: @04FS : I have edited the question. I think now it is enough to understand.

Comment: please, make a return on my answer, or should I think that it is null and that work has been useless?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a timeout or setinterval when you want to rely on real expiring time as them are not reliable. Also, notice that a refresh cancel the setTimeout/setInterval.
Instead you should use a setInterval that check every x seconds if the session has expired checking it against current Date() object.

Example:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var decodedToken = localStorage.getItem('user_token');
  if (decodedToken.exp < new Date().getTime()/1000) {
    // Token is expired
  }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: `You should not use a timeout or setinterval` and then `Instead you should use a setInterval` I get what you're saying (don't set the `setInterval` to 1800 seconds) but can you make this a little clearer in your answer.

Comment: @Mose Raguzzini:  Hi thanks for the reply. Can you please provide me a simple example.

Comment: @George thanx, but I think the OP got it

Comment: @Milind I've updated the answer with a generic snippet

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini: Thank you. Today I have edited my question. Please, can you look once again?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours on that, I hope to have gratitude back ..

```js
const
  DelayLimit     = 1,      // unit expressed in minutes, so, this is 1 minute.
  DelayChecking  = 3;     //  unit expressed in seconds, so, this is 3 seconds.


function f_Delay(ninutes2wait, seconds2Check, delayOut_fct, elapseTime_fct ) {
  let c_Delay =
  {
    rf_DelayOut      : delayOut_fct   || function(){},
    rf_ElapseTime    : elapseTime_fct || function(){},
    rf_delay         : ninutes2wait *60*1000,
    Date_Start       : Date.now(),
    Interval_ID      : null
  }

  c_Delay.Interval_ID = setInterval(function (infos) {
    let curDateDiff = Date.now() - infos.Date_Start;

    infos.rf_ElapseTime( curDateDiff );

    if (curDateDiff >= infos.rf_delay) 
    {
      infos.rf_DelayOut();
      clearInterval(infos.Interval_ID);
    }
  }, seconds2Check*1000, c_Delay );

  return c_Delay.Interval_ID;
}



function f_DelayOut() {
  outputResp.value = "time Out !"
  document.querySelectorAll('#LogOn_form > input, #LogOn_form > button').forEach(e=>e.disabled=true);
}

function f_elapseTime(milliseconds) {
  let timePass = Math.round( milliseconds / 1000 );
  outputResp.value = `time pass : ${timePass}s /  ${DelayLimit}mn`;
}

// this is the main part...
var ref_LoginDelay = f_Delay(DelayLimit, DelayChecking, f_DelayOut, f_elapseTime );

  
LogOn_form.onsubmit = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if (inputName.value==='MrJ' && inputPswd.value==='MrJ' ) 
  {
    clearInterval(ref_LoginDelay);
    outputResp.value = "Login success ! :)";

    // your stuffs 
  }
  else
  {
    LogOn_form.reset();
    outputResp.value = "bad Login.. :/";
    // document.querySelectorAll('#LogOn_form > input').forEach(e=>e.value='');
  }
}

cancel_bt.onclick = function()
{
  clearInterval(ref_LoginDelay);  //  = do Cancel f_Delay

  outputResp.value = "Login delay disabled"
}
```

```css
form { display:block; width:24em; height:12.6em; padding: 0 3em; border: 1px solid grey; margin:auto  }
form > * { display:block; float:left; margin: .5em }
label, output { clear:both;}
label { width: 6em; }
```

```html
<form id="LogOn_form">
  <h4>Please login...</h4>
  <label for="inputName"  > Name : </label>
  <input  id="inputName"  type="text"placeholder="type 'MrJ'"/>
  <label for="inputPswd"  > Password : </label>
  <input  id="inputPswd"  type="password" placeholder="type 'MrJ'"/> 
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
  <button type="reset">reset</button>
  <output id="outputResp"></output>
</form>

<br>  <br>
<button id="cancel_bt">Cancel Delay</button>
```